# Python - Webdriver Manager don't find Google Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a little Web-Scraping project with Selenium. I had to replace `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)` with `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))` because executable_path was deprecated. Here is a short snippet of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

#chrome_driver_path = "C:\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

And here's the problem, when I run the code that's the output I get:

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Could not get version for google-chrome. Is google-chrome installed?
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for None google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\User\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\102.0.5005.61\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

I installed the latest version of Selenium and the ChromeDriverManager, why can't it find Google Chrome? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re-check your `chrome_driver_path` it's seems that you're using both `/` and \

Comment: @Akzy well the chrome driver path isn't used because the executable_path is deprecated, as you can see that's why I commented it out

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same problem, the following line worked for me:

```
s=Service('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Chrome Version by opening the chrome browser > settings > About Chrome.
Make sure that you are using the same selenium chrome version that is in your chrome browser. You can download the version from this website:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: This is clearly not a solution to the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main solutions were not working for me, but I found a fix by using https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

I am on python 3.8 and using selenium 4.7.2 my IDE is anaconda and so I had to install it with the line

> conda install -c conda-forge webdriver-manager

(Note the *webdriver-manager* is the install I used and recommended on the github, not *webdriver_manager* which some other posts suggested doing but I did not)

I presume my conda approach accessed the same package, because all the recommendations provided in the github then worked for me as per below.

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

What this seems to do is download the chromedriver required when you run the script, so this avoids issues with keeping up to date with versions, it seems. The github expands on using it for different browsers.